# warning CS0642, Possible mistaken empty statement

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision

The code is supposed to stop the movement when the player hits an obstacle. Instead it stops the movement when it hit's the ground, which it's not supposed to do. Anyone know why this is happening? Here's the code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollider : MonoBehaviour{

    public PlayerMovement movement;

    void OnCollisionEnter(UnityEngine.Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        if(collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle");
        {
            movement.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well your ground probably has a Obstacle tag within it. Or your layers for the tag are wrong.

Comment: Remove the `;` at the end of your `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a semicolon after the if statement. Right now your code stops the if statement as soon it's declared so the movement gets disabled on any collision. Remove the semicolon and as long as the code in PlayerMovement is correct, it should work.